# Unboxing does not create a copy of the value. Is this right?

Tags: c#, .net

I was reading Microsoft's Class Room Training Materil. I read the following

Unboxing
Unboxing is the opposite of boxing. It is the explicit conversion of a reference type to a
value type. Unboxing retrieves a reference to the value type contained within an object.
An unboxing operation involves checking the object instance to ensure that the object
instance is a boxed value of the given value type. Then, the value from the instance is
copied into the value type variable.

**

**Unboxing returns a pointer to the data within a boxed object and does not create a copy of the data.**

**

I dont really understand the line that i highlighted. it says that when unboxing boxed object, it does not create a copy, it just returns a pointer. If that is true, then a value type variable will be allocated in Heap right?

Ram

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, it's true, but not the whole picture.

The unboxing itself only returns a pointer to the data, but you can't use that to access the data in C#. When you have unboxed a value in C#, you always copy it somewhere.

Example:

```
object o = 42; //box
int i = (int)o; //unbox
```

The unboxing iself gets the pointer to the value `42` in the object `o`, then the value is copied into the variable `i`.

Comment: Is there anywhere the pointer to unboxed value can be directly used without copying the value?

Comment: @RAM: I don't think so, at least not easily. Perhaps you can use `fixed` to pin the object in memory, and get a pointer to the value, but that would be a lot more complicated than just copying the value. Values that get boxed are small, so there is no real reason to try to avoid copying it.

Comment: @colinfang: Unboxing a value gets a pointer to the value that is in the object, it doesn't copy the value until you actually use it for something. Unboxing a struct and using a field in it will copy the value of that field out from the boxed struct.

Answer (score 21):

In addition to what Guffa said, here is some additional information:

- The “unboxing” operation described by the text you quoted **describes the `unbox` CIL instruction.** The CIL standard has this to say about `unbox`:

  > Unlike `box`, which is required to make
  >   a copy of a value type for use in the
  >   object, `unbox` is *not* required to copy
  >   the value type from the object.
  >   Typically it simply computes the
  >   address of the value type that is
  >   already present inside of the boxed
  >   object
- **The unboxing conversions you use in C# are *not* compiled to `unbox`.** They are compiled to another instruction called `unbox.any`:

  > [...] the `unbox.any` instruction extracts the value contained within
  >   *obj* (of type `O`). (It is equivalent to `unbox` followed by `ldobj`.)

  In English, this means `unbox.any` does an unboxing operation (`unbox`) — which pushes a *pointer* onto the evaluation stack — followed by the copy operation (`ldobj`), which converts the pointer to the actual value contained in the value type and pushes that on the evaluation stack instead.

  For completeness, here is the description of `ldobj`:

  > The `ldobj` instruction copies a value
  >   to the evaluation stack. [...] *src* is an unmanaged pointer
  >   (native int), or a managed pointer
  >   (&). [...]
  >
  > [Rationale: The
  >   `ldobj` instruction can be used to pass
  >   a value type as an argument. *end
  >   rationale*]

As far as I am aware, the C# compiler never uses `unbox` or `ldobj`, it always uses `unbox.any` to do unboxing, and `ldind.*` to dereference references (such as `ref`/`out` parameters).

Comment: very clear explanation. From the answers given by you and Guffa, I clearly understand Unboxing. Thank you for your great explanation and time - Ram