# Unboxing. Copy of fields to stack in most of cases

Tags: c#, clr, boxing, unboxing

Richter "CLR via C#" famous book

I understand, when do unboxing, it returns pointer to unboxed value on heap, but i cant get pointer in C#, so there is copy of fields from heap to stack done (answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743762/unboxing-does-not-create-a-copy-of-the-value-is-this-right)).

But, when i do

```
Console.WriteLine(v + ", " + (Int32)o);
```

so, when i do unboxing of object "o", only pointer passed, without copy. 
"...This requires an unboxing operation (but no copy operation)..."
(Richter, page 129)

Now, my question is: when return pointer to unboxed value on heap and when it also copied to the stack?

Thanks

P.S.: code:

```
        Int32 v = 5;
        Object o = v;
        Console.WriteLine(v + ", " + (Int32)o);
```

Comment: The code is copied verbatim from Richter's book (minus 1 line), and compiles normally.

Answer (score 1):

The `unbox` itself doesn't copy the value. But the value is nonetheless copied when it's used. In your example from Richter's book, the `box` operation that immediately follows copies the value into a new boxed value.

Comment: Hi Philippe! Thanks for answer, but my question was:
while doing unboxing when value copied and when not
Thanks

Comment: @zzfima The value is never copied **when** unboxing, but it is almost always copied **afterward**, when using the value. I don't know of any C# code that would compile to an `unbox` not followed by some kind of copying (even `unsafe` code with `&` operator), but you could certainly do it directly in IL.

Comment: in my example "Console.WriteLine(v + ", " + (Int32)o)" Richter said, that when doing unboxing of "o" it is not copied, only pointer returns

Comment: @zzfima Sure. And then the value inside the box for `o` is boxed again (thus copying it inside the new box) for the call to `String.Concat()`. That's why Richter said you may be surprised there are actually 3 `boxing`. There is not a first copy from the box to the stack, and then a second copy to the second box, only a copy from the first box directly to the second one.